# How do I print the text content of HTML::Treebuilder nodes on separate lines?

Tags: perl, html-parsing, perl-module

I'm using **TreeBuilder::XPath** as shown below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath; 

my $url='file:///C:/Users/Rockstar/workspace/abc/globals_func.html';
my $page = get($url) or die $!;

my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $page);
my @trips= $p->findnodes( '//div[@class="contents"]');
foreach my $trip (@trips){
   print $trip->as_text; 
}
```

After running it in an HTML file, I get this output (ALL in one line):

> ChainCtrlBuildChain() : ChainController.cChainCtrlDumpChain() : ChainController.cChainCtrlExit() : ChainController.cChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan() : ChainController.cChainCtrlInit() : ChainController.c.

But I want them to be shown as below (one row per value):

```
ChainCtrlBuildChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlDumpChain() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlExit() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan() : ChainController.c
ChainCtrlInit() : ChainController.c.
```

My HTML file (displaying only the HTML code of "contents"):

```html
<div class="contents">
&#160;<ul>
<li>ChainCtrlBuildChain()
: <a class="el"   href="_chain_controller_8c.html#acb2c56087a2072b6445a54c17662d118">ChainController.c</a>
</li>
<li>ChainCtrlDumpChain()
: <a class="el" href="_chain_controller_8c.html#a13ed5a02bf232b115b9a58cdd13dadd7">ChainController.c</a>
</li>
<li>ChainCtrlExit()
: <a class="el" href="_chain_controller_8c.html#a9e30e46ebc5411537efe95a286e27cb4">ChainController.c</a>
</li>
<li>ChainCtrlGetBitStreamChan()
: <a class="el" href="_chain_controller_8c.html#a00faa6e64ea466d4ec57339017e57e71">ChainController.c</a>
</li>
<li>ChainCtrlInit()
: <a class="el" href="_chain_controller_8c.html#aed300a388eff2fa9c7565025982faab1">ChainController.c</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- contents -->
```

What am I missing?

Comment: My XPath Skills are a little bit rusty but i think you need to access the `<li>` elements in your `<ul>`

Comment: Can you help me with how to access <li> elements in your <ul>. I am new to perl.Thanks

Comment: `//div[@class="contents"]//li`

Comment: I was trying different perl modules.but didn't know that i just need to add "//li". Thanks a lot. u saved me a lot of time and work.As i am new to perl and these module syntax are not so clear in CPAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new line to your `print` statement.

```
print $trip->as_text."\n";
```

Alternatively you can use `say` to do that automatically:

```
use feature 'say';
...
say $trip->as_text;
```

---

**UPDATE**

You are accessing the `div` element, which gives you one element in your array with every element of your `ul` together. To get every element of your `li` into one array element you need to do this:

```
use feature 'say';
...
my @trips= $p->findnodes( '//div[@class="contents"]//li');
foreach my $trip (@trips){
   say $trip->as_text; 
}
```

This will access the `li` elements.

Comment: i tired "\n" earlier but it dnt help .                                say $trip->as_text; also gives the output as one line. I feel I am missing something in "$p->findnodes( '//div[@class="contents"]')".

Comment: How does your HTML look like? Maybe there is only one div with all information in it.

Comment: I have put my HTML code in the question.Yes there is only one div with all the information.can I put them one row per value. Thanks for the help

Comment: i will try "access the <li> elements in your <ul>" now. Thanks for the help